# What is the difference between closing #HotIf and return in AutoHotkey v2?

Tags: autohotkey

Basically, what is the difference between this

```
#HotIf MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
  WheelUp::Volume_Up
  WheelDown::Volume_Down
#HotIf

; Other code that follows
```

and this?

```
#HotIf MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
  WheelUp::Volume_Up
  WheelDown::Volume_Down
Return

; Other code that follows
```

Also, do I even need closing #HotIf (or return)?

What if I write this?

```
#HotIf MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
  WheelUp::Volume_Up
  WheelDown::Volume_Down

; Other code that follows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Return` doesn't do anything here.
In v1 you used to end a hotkey block with `Return`, like so:

```
a::
    MsgBox
Return
```

<sub><sup>(Thought, this does not apply for one-liner hotkeys, like in your example. They always just execute the one single line)</sup></sub>

But in v2, hotkey blocks are enclosed in `{ }`, so `Return` isn't used here:

```
a::
{
    MsgBox()
}
```

---

Ok, then onto the next question, why do you need `#HotIf`?
Well it ends the context sensitive block. If you never end your context sensitive block, it never ends.

Consider this

```
#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe notepad.exe")
a::MsgBox("notepad specific hotkey 1")
b::MsgBox("notepad specific hotkey 2")

;something else 
;something else

MyCoolFunction()
{
    ;somethingthing
}

MyCoolFunction2()
{
    ;somethingthing
}

c::MsgBox("Oops, I forgot to end the context sensitive hotkey block, and now this hotkey can only be used in notepad")
```

---

What you should've done, is:

```
#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe notepad.exe")
a::MsgBox("notepad specific hotkey 1")
b::MsgBox("notepad specific hotkey 2")
#HotIf

; something else 
; something else

MyCoolFunction()
{
    ;somethingthing
}

MyCoolFunction2()
{
    ;somethingthing
}

c::MsgBox("Now I can be used outside of notepad, as intended")
```